# Passing 20,000 objects between Workers > Performance Hit?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to create about 20,000 "Person" objects in a worker, and then pass them to the main application.

I understand that these objects will be cloned between threads and that "Person" support AMF serialization.

But I worry about performance - will my game suffer any performance hit when receiving those thousands of objects? will the current frame get stuck? or does AIR take care of it, and it will be a smooth transaction?

Will be thankful for any help on this issue.

Thanks

Update:

The objects I am creating are sort of animation instructions, not BOTs o AI.

They are downloaded in binary format, and get serialized to AS3 objects.

My game must load them during active play, and today I pay a painful price of 4-5 frames getting stuck.

If Workers would download and create them, and if the main thread would receive them without getting stuck - I would call it a victory...
I want only 1 thread, which will create about 20,000 objects.
That background thread will send those objects to the main thread.
If the main thread won't get stuck when receiving/deserializing the objects - challenge achieved.

So my hope is that the deserialization on the main thread doesn't stick it.

Am I on the right path?

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Do you actually **need** to use a **Worker** here? With this setup it might be easier and faster just to create them on the main thread rather than go lengths to devise a **Worker** only to re-create these objects again in the main thread by the means of de-serialization.

Comment: Workers are not designed to *create* objects, they are more to *process* objects. So you should create them in main thread. Yes this will cause a freeze, but you can create them in smaller batches, one per frame, to not stall the app.

Comment: **UPD**: I advise to follow the Vesper's advice: split the whole bulk into smaller chunks that can be processed in the main thread over the course of several frames. Like, 1000 per frame, 20 frames, less than 1 second and you also can display some kind of "please wait while loading" progress to smoothen the user's experience.

Comment: My point is: you need to solve the **REAL** problem here, which is not the application stuttering while processing the huge bulk of data (it is quite expected), but the ugly lag users might experience. So, you shouldn't go the **Worker** way, which is complicated, impacts the overall performance even worse, and might even not improve that lag (because passing and de-serializing 20K objects could be a larger workload than just creating them), but instead you should devise an UX solution which masks that lag for users or presents it in a tolerable way.

Comment: So AIR won't create those objects "silently" when transfering to main thread? what a shame... that could be a pure threading solution ...
Indeed, I could ceate those objects in a worker thread, and then pass them to the main thread in bulks so AMF deserialziation won't hurt gameplay... but to employ workers just for that seems overdesign...

Comment: @YoonesMashayekhi In the main thread you still need to **read** these objects (from shared **ByteArray** presumably) because threads don't share the scope, reading bytes (or objects) is a **synchronous** operation that still eats **CPU** time and power. So, no, there are no smart tricks here to help.

Comment: Yea, well the problem is that the worker doesnt have shared memory with the main thread. If you have other logic used to determine the properties of the object, then doing this on a worker and then passing them to the main thread with a asynchronous operation like I linked to, would probably be the best approach. Greenthreading has its limits and you still need to allocate a minimum amount of frame time to any logic being executed there

Comment: This can bog up the main thread a bit, and while not blocking, it could cause a framerate drop. This is why you will see an argument called maxScriptTime in my extension, which is by default 16 I believe (to assume 60fps). But you want to make sure your maximum time is enough to handle at least a single iteration in your loop or it will never complete.

Comment: If this is the case, you may have to break up your logic into several asynchronous operations or make some adjustments to my code to ensure that atleast 1 iteration happens per frame. I may make a commit to that effect in the near future in the repo.